# How to auto-populate search bar in ASP.NET MVC ? I do have list of json objects from action method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have list of objects with me I need to call them to search bar as user enters data. I have tried jQuery but no luck. I need to know how can i connect list objects to view.

Comment: can you please provide what you have so far?

Comment: Have you checked the jquery autocomplete feature: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

Juery Provide the built in method for filter the data

you can use jquery.DataTable Method

HomeController.cs

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Data()
        {
            List<Student> st = (from stud in this.studDBContext.students select stud).ToList();
            return Json(new { data = st });
        }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<TestCore.Models.Student>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<table class="table" id="studentdatatable"> 
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Id
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Address
            </th>
            <th>
                ImageCaption
            </th>
            <th>
                ImageDescription
            </th>
            <th>
                ImageName
            </th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        
    </tbody>
</table>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
@* Load datatable css *@
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@* Load datatable js *@
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#studentdatatable').DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: "/Home/Data",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    return JSON.stringify(data);
                }
            },
            columns: [
                { data: "id" }, //first letter be small 
                { data: "name" },
                { data: "address" },
                { data: "imageCaption" },
                { data: "imageDescription" },
                { data: "imageName" }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

[I have an four record in my datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1mMu.png)

[see Index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqtRE.png)

[when I search reacord then get only particular record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfue7.png)